# Pandas: create pivot table with duplicate index and show information (no counts, just data)

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I have the following dataframe:

```
    ID    KEY   TYPE  FIELD   VALUE
0   MYID  112233  1     Height  117
1   MYID  112233  1     Weight  17
2   MYID  445566  1     Height  95
3   MYID  445566  1     Weight  39
4   MYID  112233  2     Height  118
5   MYID  112233  2     Weight  17
```

This has duplicate `KEY` values, and I need to keep the ones with the highest `TYPE`. The intended result is:

```
   KEY    TYPE Height  Weight
0  112233 2    118     17
1  445566 1    95      39
```

I tried accomplishing this using `pd.pivot(index='KEY', columns='FIELD')['VALUE']` but it complains because I have duplicate values in `KEY`. I also tried using `pd.pivot_table()` but this is inadequate for this problem as I don't have to aggregate data, just show them.

How could I solve this?

Comment: Use `set_index` + `unstack` alternative

Comment: Would you like to make this an answer?

Comment: It is dupe, so rather not.